# Why can IntelliJ only 'compile' certain resources?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm running 10.5.2 community edition.  I have marked

src/main/resources

as a source directory.  I can right click and 'compile' certain files which as far as I can tell just means the IDE copies the file to the same directory level as "com.mydomain.packages" where class files are sent.  My question is how come I can 'compile' XML and HTML but when I right click on CSV the compile option is greyed out?

Comment: Your IDE probably tries to "execute" your XML as XSLT stylesheet, and tries to do the same with the HTML (treating it as XHTML/XML).

Comment: If you are using a maven project, shouldn't you be using this to build your project. Perhaps IntelliJ doesn't know what you want the compile to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as configured under Settings>Compiler

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/compiler.html

Comment: This was useful to exclude logback.groovy from the compile. Just add logback.groovy as a resource pattern.